# Need advices with Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I've understood the routing principle consisting in creating routes and call them from twig templates.
When calling, we can pass parameters to the route which will be included in the url.

I'm in the following case, I have an object called "Object" and each object can belong to other objects called "Category".
In my twig template, I display all my objects line by line (each row contains the object information and a checkbox to select it).
I have also a button "send", I'd like to click this button and edit all the selected objects.

However I don't think I can do this with a route because I don't know by advance how many elements will be selected (so I don't know the number of parameters to the route).

I'd like to know how you would do this.

Comment: Could you please provide some codes and give an real example ?

Comment: Why not use a form for that?

Comment: Are the objects related to categories through entities and do you have a parent object which has many categories as children? (OneToMany)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the tardive response, I have the following code in my twig tempalte :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-stripped">
    <tr>
        <td> Delete </td>
        <td> Title </td>
        <td> Date added </td>
        <td> Description </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    {% for link in links %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="btn" href="{{ path('ProjectTestBundle_deleteLink', {'idLink': link.id}) }}"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td> <a>{{link.title}}</a> </td>
        <td> {{link.dateAjout|date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}} </td>
        <td> {{link.description}} </td>
        <td>
            <input id="{{link.id}}" type="checkbox"">
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<a class="btn">
    <i class="icon-edit"></i>
            Add selected links to a theme
</a>
```

What I'd like to is to put a href attribute there

```
<a href="" class="btn">
    <i class="icon-edit"></i>
            Add selected links to a theme
</a>
```

and call a path with all the links selected with the checkbox.